Error en validación de NULL utilizando un procedure de SNOWFLAKE
Tengo este procedure creado, el problema es que al querer verificar si es NULL :DATE_FROM me devuelve un error, ya probé quitandole los dos puntos, probé utilizando TRIM y COALLESCE y tampoCo me funciona, que podría ser? el error puede estar en otra parte? Deje '...' en algunas partes para mantener privacidad,
ERROR:Syntax error: unexpected ':'. (line 1194)
syntax error line 41 at position 26 unexpected 'IS'.
syntax error line 42 at position 21 unexpected 'period_value'.
syntax error line 43 at position 20 unexpected 'WHEN'. (line 1194
    PROCESS_INDEX NUMERIC,
    DATE_FROM VARCHAR DEFAULT NULL,
    DATE_TO VARCHAR DEFAULT NULL
)
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE SQL
AS
DECLARE 
    calculated_date_from DATE;
    calculated_date_to DATE;
    step INT;
    function_name STRING;
    source_table STRING;
    dimensions STRING;
    lag_time INT;
    notes STRING;
    final_query STRING DEFAULT '';
    period_value STRING;
BEGIN
    FOR row_index IN (
        SELECT STEP, FUNCTION_NAME, SOURCE_TABLE, DIMENSIONS, PERIOD, LAG_TIME, NOTES
        FROM ...
        WHERE INDEX = :PROCESS_INDEX
        ORDER BY STEP
    )
    DO
        step := row_index.STEP;
        function_name := row_index.FUNCTION_NAME;
        source_table := row_index.SOURCE_TABLE;
        dimensions := row_index.DIMENSIONS;
        lag_time := row_index.LAG_TIME;
        notes := row_index.NOTES;

        FOR period_row IN (
            SELECT VALUE AS period_value
            FROM TABLE(FLATTEN(INPUT => PARSE_JSON(row_index.PERIOD)))
        )
        DO
            period_value := LOWER(period_row.period_value);
            IF :DATE_FROM IS NULL THEN
                CASE period_value
                    WHEN 'daily' THEN
                        calculated_date_from := DATEADD(DAY, -1, CURRENT_DATE());
                        calculated_date_to := calculated_date_from;
                    WHEN 'weekly' THEN
                        calculated_date_from := DATEADD(WEEK, -1, TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE(), 'WEEK'));
                        calculated_date_to := DATEADD(DAY, 6, calculated_date_from);
                    WHEN 'monthly' THEN
                        calculated_date_from := DATEADD(MONTH, -1, TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE(), 'MONTH'));
                        calculated_date_to := LAST_DAY(calculated_date_from);
                    ELSE
                        RAISE EXCEPTION 'Unsupported periodicity: %', period_row.period_value;
                END CASE;
            ELSE
                calculated_date_from := :DATE_FROM;
                calculated_date_to := :DATE_TO;
            END IF;

            final_query := final_query || '
                INSERT INTO ...(
                    ...,...,...
                )
                SELECT 
                    ''' || period_row.period_value || ''' AS PERIOD_COLUMN,
                    ''' || calculated_date_from || ''' AS START_DATE, 
                    ''' || calculated_date_to || ''' AS END_DATE, 
                    REGION, 
                    DISTRIBUTION_PLATFORM AS PLATFORM, 
                    SUBS_PARTNER, 
                    STREAMS, 
                    NULL AS ACTIVATIONS,
                    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() AS EXECUTION_TIMESTAMP, 
                    ''' || notes || ''' AS NOTES
                FROM TABLE(
                    CALL ...(
                        ''' || function_name || ''',
                        ''' || dimensions || ''',
                        ''' || source_table || ''',
                        ''' || period_row.period_value || ''',
                        ''' || calculated_date_from || ''',
                        ''' || calculated_date_to || '''
                    )
                )';

        END FOR;
    END FOR;

    RETURN final_query;
END;```


¿Funcionan los IF sin paréntesis en snowflake?

en snowflake si

Yo diría que no...

verifiqué poniendo los parentesis y me sigue figurando el mismo error

En el IF, pone DATE_FROM y en el PROCESS_INDEX del where. Y deberias convertir la fecha a DATE
